# Prometheus configuration some hosts with proxy, some without

Tags: yaml, prometheus

I have a `prometheus.yml` and I don't want that my homeserver goes thru proxy. I tried to use `proxy_url` with the targets but that doesn't work.

Here is my working (except homeserver) `prometheus.yml`. Is there any way to exclude the proxy on this host?

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'node'

    proxy_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888' 

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.178.3:9100']
        labels:
          instance: homeserver
      - targets: ['www.fddfg.de:9100']
        labels:
          instance: 1ahf
      - targets: ['435435346774:9100']
        labels:
          instance: dfgsd
      - targets: ['207.148.107.219:9100']
        labels:
          instance: vultr-1
      - targets: ['198.55.47.29:9100']
        labels:
          instance: vultr-2

    basic_auth:
        username: 'prometheus'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define proxies per jobs. This means you can split your targets in jobs and assign proxy per job:

```
global:   
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'node'
    proxy_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888' 
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['www.fddfg.de:9100']
        labels:
          instance: 1ahf
      - targets: ['435435346774:9100']
        labels:
          instance: dfgsd
      - targets: ['207.148.107.219:9100']
        labels:
          instance: vultr-1
      - targets: ['198.55.47.29:9100']
        labels:
          instance: vultr-2
    basic_auth:
        username: 'prometheus'

  - job_name: 'node-homeserver'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['192.168.178.3:9100']
        labels:
          instance: homeserver
    basic_auth:
        username: 'prometheus'
```

I think the yaml above could be the solution to your issue.